# Insert variable and looping with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

In data.txt I have:

1. LEW01,14/01/2016,07:50:00,15.6,-19,943,-8.7,-228,-19,943,-8.7,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,
2. LEW01,14/01/2016,08:00:00,16.2,-18,944,-8.6,-229,-19,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,

How can I insert Z in this manner:

1. LEW01,14/01/2016,07:50:00,15.6,-19,943,-8.7,-228,-19,943,-8.7,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,"Z"
2. LEW01,14/01/2016,08:00:00,16.2,-18,944,-8.6,-229,-19,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,"Z"

using a loop, please??

where Z in line 1 is `15.6*-19+943` (column 4*column 5+ column 6)
and
where Z in line 2 is `16.2*-18+944` (column 4*column 5+ column 6 too)

thanks before

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code.

Comment: You have to read line a line and concat what you want to the final of what you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` library to manipulate table data.

```python
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: %cat input.txt
LEW01,14/01/2016,07:50:00,15.6,-19,943,-8.7,-228,-19,943,-8.7,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:00:00,16.2,-18,944,-8.6,-229,-19,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', header=None)

In [5]: df[15] = df[3] * df[4] + df[5]

In [10]: df.to_csv('output.txt', header=None, index=False)

In [11]: %cat output.txt
LEW01,14/01/2016,07:50:00,15.6,-19,943,-8.7,-228,-19,943,-8.7,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,646.6
LEW01,14/01/2016,08:00:00,16.2,-18,944,-8.6,-229,-19,943,-8.6,-0.9,48.5,4.14,12.39,652.4
```

Comment: thank you so much Sir  MinHwan Kim, you are very clever and good answer, its work... Thanks a lot